# when trying to instal wickRme on 18.04 I get the following error

Tags: software-installation, dependencies, libraries, symbolic-link, gdebi

```
sudo gdebi WickrMe_4.44.04-01_amd64.deb
```

...

```
This package is uninstallable
Dependency is not satisfiable: libicu55
```

Then I tried searching for a match

```
apt-cache search libicu
```

but on install attempt

```
libicu60 is already the newest version (60.2-3ubuntu3).
```

Why is newer 60 not good enough for the 55 requirement?  And if that doesn't matter how can I overcome this problem?

Comment: I used https://shazwazza.com/post/installing-net-core-101-on-ubuntu-1610/ to install the missing bit to allow installation to continue.  Surely, it is not as unwise as the initial respondent suggested?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an Ubuntu problem. The WikrMe download page *clearly* states that their package is for 16.04, not 18.04.

`libicu60` is the *name* of the package. The names must match.

That the name also includes the version number is nice to know, but otherwise irrelevant - the package manager only knows that the names don't match.

`libicu55` is included in (only) Ubuntu 16.04, which gives you three choices:

- You can try installing the 16.04 package in your 18.04 system. This is expert-level stuff, and you are LIKELY to break your system quite horribly if you try. DON'T do it. If you really want to destroy your system, backup your data first.
- You can seek a newer version of your deb that uses `libicu60`. This is the easiest solution, and most common in the Linux world, where new versions are released constantly. You should complain to the WikrMe developers that their crummy app is stale and needs to be updated for 18.04 if they want Ubuntu folks to use it. Better yet, they should snappify it so it's release-independent.
- You can install 16.04 in a second partition (or more likely a VM) so you can use it with the rest of your system. It will add a bit of overhead, depending upon how you configure it.

Obviously, the BEST solution is for you to use a supported and compatible messaging application instead of WikrMe. There are many good candidates in the Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: It clearly states by contrast it supports only a 64bit version.  Why cannot a newer version of ubuntu lts perform as well as a prior lts?  " If you really want to destroy your system"  sarcasm, really? ". It will add a bit of overhead," this seems like expert territory also

Comment: "There are many good candidates in the Ubuntu Software Center"  which have audited end-to-end encryption? that also do not require use of Legacy Texting (sms)?

Comment: Not sarcasm - look at `apt rdepends libicu60` and see exactly what will break.

Comment: It's not a matter of 'perform as well as a prior LTS'. WikrMe chose to package as a deb for 16.04...and nothing else. They could have chosen a set of libraries that *are* compatible across all releases of Ubuntu. WikrMe could have packaged a deb for 18.04. WikrMe could have packaged a snap. Any of those choices would make your install trivial. Feel free to complain to the WikrMe developers about the choices they made.